# Getting day of week from date column in prestosql?

Tags: sql, date, data-science, presto, trino

I have a date column called **day** such as `2019/07/22` if I want to create a custom field that translates that date to the actual day of week it is such as **Sunday** or **Monday** how is this possible? I cant seem to find a method that works for presto sql.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`format_datetime`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#format_datetime) function to extract the day of week from a date or timestamp:

```sql
SELECT format_datetime(day, 'E')
FROM (
  VALUES DATE '2019-07-22'
) t(day)
```

produces:

```
 _col0
-------
 Mon
```

If you want the full name of the day, use `format_datetime(day, 'EEEE')`:

```
 _col0
-------
 Monday
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try extract('day' from day ) as day_name.